# How to convert CBDescriptor Value to String?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I can able to read the descriptor value in the method "didUpdateValeFor descriptor:". Below is the log of the descriptor that I get from the BLE device.

`<CBDescriptor: 0x1c445cb60, UUID = Characteristic Format, value = <08ff2427 013110>>`

Values are in data format which is of some valid range from **XX** value to **YY** value and it is of type **uint32** i guess. I couldn't able to convert them. I'm not able to get any solution from other answers.

Comment: Unsigned 32 bit integer format.

Comment: Check [this page](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.characteristic_presentation_format.xml), which explains how 7 bytes are organized. 0x08 for `unsigned 32-bit integer`, 0x2724 for [`Unit: Pascal`](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/units), 0x1031 for Description Information (please search by yourself if you can get some string representation for it). 0xFF and 0x01 have no significant meaning. Better visit the bluetooth site and contact to the vendor of the device.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the `CBDescriptor` has a `uuid` property which will be one of the values specified [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbdescriptor) and a `value` property.  The type of the `value` property will depend on the `uuid`.  You can find the relevant `value` type in each of the possible CBDescriptor uuids.  For example, for `CBUUIDCharacteristicFormatString` the `value` is a `Data` instance that encodes the format string.

A sample function that decodes a `CBDescriptor` is shown below. You would need to add the missing uuid types.

```
func descriptorDescription(for descriptor: CBDescriptor) -> String {

    var description: String?
    var value: String?

    switch descriptor.uuid.uuidString {
    case CBUUIDCharacteristicFormatString:
        if let data = descriptor.value as? Data {
            description = "Characteristic format: "
            value = data.description
        }
    case CBUUIDCharacteristicUserDescriptionString:
        if let val = descriptor.value as? String {
            description = "User description: "
            value = val
        }
    case CBUUIDCharacteristicExtendedPropertiesString:
        if let val = descriptor.value as? NSNumber {
            description = "Extended Properties: "
            value = val.description
        }
    case CBUUIDClientCharacteristicConfigurationString:
        if let val = descriptor.value as? NSNumber {
            description = "Client characteristic configuration: "
            value = val.description
        }
    case CBUUIDServerCharacteristicConfigurationString:
        if let val = descriptor.value as? NSNumber {
            description = "Server characteristic configuration: "
            value = val.description
        }
    case CBUUIDCharacteristicAggregateFormatString:
        if let val = descriptor.value as? String {
            description = "Characteristic aggregate format: "
            value = val
        }
    default:
        break
    }

    if let desc=description, let val = value  {
        return "\(desc)\(val)"
    } else {
        return "Unknown descriptor"
    }
}
```

For the specific decoding of the data associated with `CBUUIDCharacteristicFormatString` you need to refer to the [Bluetooth documentation](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.characteristic_presentation_format.xml)